# Set background image on single template page only

Tags: html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I am using WordPress with Kleo theme and Buddypress.

I want to set the background image on a single template page (registration page).

The existing CSSis huge and I dont know which bits to change but when it is changed causes a change on all pages.

I have tried setting the background color `background-color:#f00;` and that works but it changes the color on all site pages.

When I use `background-image: url("gen-up-background.png") !important;}`
 it has no effect.

I want to set the background image on this page:

[Page to edit](http://52.209.186.138/register/)

1. I am not sure what CSS I should use to target this page only?
2. Is the above the correct CSS to display an image?

Existing CSS:

```css
.main-color hr, .main-color.container-wrap, #footer.main-color, #socket.main-color, .main-color.social-header, .main-color .top-menu .tabdrop::before, .main-color #top-social .tabdrop::before, .main-color #top-social, .main-color .top-menu > ul, .main-color .kleo-main-header, .main-color .template-page, .main-color .sidebar-right, .main-color .sidebar-left, .main-color .sidebar-extra, .main-color .sidebar-main, .main-color .hr-title, .main-color .nav-tabs, .main-color .nav-pills > li > a, .main-color .kleo-tabs .nav .open > a.dropdown-toggle, .main-color .kleo-tabs .nav .open > a.dropdown-toggle:hover, .main-color .kleo-tabs .nav .open > a.dropdown-toggle:focus, .main-color .kleo-tabs .tabdrop .dropdown-menu, .main-color .dropdown-menu, .main-color .kleo-toggle-menu .kleo-toggle-submenu::before, .main-color #ajax_search_container::before, .main-color #top-social li a, .main-color .top-menu li > a, .main-color .pagination > li > a, .main-color .pagination > li > span, .main-color .callout-blockquote blockquote, .main-color .masonry-listing .post-content, .main-color .list-divider li, .main-color #ajax_search_container, .main-color .form-control, .main-color .feature-item:hover .feature-icon, .main-color .bordered-icons .feature-item.default-icons-size .feature-icon, .main-color .bordered-icons .feature-item.big-icons-size .feature-icon, .main-color input[type="text"], .main-color input[type="password"], .main-color input[type="date"], .main-color input[type="datetime"], .main-color input[type="datetime-local"], .main-color input[type="month"], .main-color input[type="week"], .main-color input[type="email"], .main-color input[type="number"], .main-color input[type="search"], .main-color input[type="tel"], .main-color input[type="time"], .main-color input[type="url"], .main-color textarea, .main-color .activity-timeline, .main-color #buddypress div.item-list-tabs ul li a span, .main-color #buddypress button, .buddypress .main-color a.button, .main-color #buddypress a.button, .main-color #buddypress input[type="submit"], .main-color #buddypress input[type="button"], .main-color #buddypress input[type="reset"], .main-color #buddypress ul.button-nav li a, .main-color #buddypress div.generic-button a, .main-color.bp-full-width-profile div.generic-button a, .main-color #buddypress .comment-reply-link, .main-color #buddypress #whats-new, .main-color #buddypress div.message-search, .main-color #buddypress div.dir-search, .main-color #buddypress .activity-read-more, .main-color #bp-login-widget-submit, .main-color .bbp_widget_login .button.user-submit, .main-color #wp-calendar caption, .main-color .wp-caption, .main-color .widget .woocommerce-product-search, .main-color .widget form#bbp-search-form > div, .main-color .page-content #searchform > div, .main-color .widget_search #searchform > div, .main-color #bp-login-widget-form input[type="text"], .main-color #bp-login-widget-form input[type="password"], .main-color .bbp-login-form input[type="text"], .main-color #buddypress #friend-list .friend-inner-list, .main-color #buddypress #member-list .member-inner-list, .main-color #buddypress #members-list .member-inner-list, .main-color #buddypress #groups-list .group-inner-list, .main-color #buddypress div#item-nav .tabdrop .dropdown-menu, .main-color #buddypress div.profile, .main-color #buddypress #friend-list div.action .generic-button a.send-message, .main-color #buddypress #member-list div.action .generic-button a.send-message, .main-color #buddypress #members-list div.action .generic-button a.send-message, .main-color #buddypress form.standard-form .left-menu img.avatar, .main-color .checkbox-mark, .main-color #buddypress div#group-create-tabs ul li.current a, .main-color .rtmedia-container #rtMedia-queue-list tr td, .main-color #buddypress .standard-form textarea, .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="text"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="color"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="date"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="datetime"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="datetime-local"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="email"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="month"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="number"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="range"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="search"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="tel"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="time"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="url"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="week"], .main-color #buddypress .standard-form select, .main-color #buddypress .standard-form input[type="password"], .main-color #buddypress .dir-search input[type="search"], .main-color #buddypress .dir-search input[type="text"], .main-color .bbp-pagination-links a, .main-color .bbp-pagination-links span, .main-color #bbpress-forums li.bbp-body ul.forum, .main-color #bbpress-forums li.bbp-body ul.topic, .main-color form#new-post, .main-color #bbpress-forums .bbp-form input[type="text"], .main-color .quicktags-toolbar, .main-color .wp_themeSkin tr.mceFirst td.mceToolbar, .main-color .quicktags-toolbar input, .main-color .wp-editor-area, .main-color .rtmedia-container .rtmedia_next_prev a, .main-color .rtmedia-activity-container .rtmedia_next_prev a, .main-color #buddypress div.rtmedia-activity-container .rtmedia_next_prev a, .main-color #rtm-gallery-title-container #rtm-media-options, .main-color #rtMedia-upload-button, .main-color #buddypress #item-body .rtmedia-item-comments .rt_media_comment_form textarea, .main-color .rtmedia-container .rtmedia-editor-main dl.tabs dd > a, .main-color .rtmedia-activity-container .rtmedia-editor-main dl.tabs dd > a, .main-color #buddypress div.rtmedia-activity-container .rtmedia-editor-main dl.tabs dd > a, .main-color .rtmedia-container .imgedit-wrap div.imgedit-settings .imgedit-group, .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container textarea, .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="text"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="text"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="color"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="date"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="datetime"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="datetime-local"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="email"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="month"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="number"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="range"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="search"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="tel"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="time"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="url"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="week"], .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container select, .main-color #buddypress .rtmedia-container input[type="password"], .main-color .kleo-toggle-menu .kleo-toggle-submenu, .main-color .kleo-toggle-menu a.remove, .main-color .woocommerce .kleo-cart-totals .totals-wrap, .main-color .kleo-toggle-menu .minicart-buttons .btn-default, .main-color .kleo_ajax_results h4, .main-color .ajax_view_all, .main-color #articles-dir-list article.article-container
```

Comment: hello,@Gavin Reynoldson I have found solution.

Comment: Theme have its  own characterstics here this theme follow the bootrap col structure.I admin panle you have Visual editor go there and set background color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can style a specific page on WordPress using the Page ID.

For example:

```
.page-id-1 body {
    background-image: url("gen-up-background.png");
}
```

The above code will set the page background with an ID of 1 to the image provided.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Just tried that with `page-id-2833`. It didnt work. When I look at the CSS on Firebug the list is huge but it affects a change if I edit it. Im just not sure which of the hundreds of selectors I need to call.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson have you tried using https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-stylesheets/?

Answer (score 0):

Theme have its own characterstics here this theme follow the bootrap col structure.I admin panle you have Visual editor go there and set background color.
Sorry,But I am quite poor in css.

```
 .page-id-2833 body #buddypress{
     background-image: url("gen-up-background.png");
    }
```

Case 2:
find and add this code inspect element.I have done with this it working.

```
<div class="template-page col-sm-12 tpl-no" style="
    background-image: url(&quot;http://imagecolony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Abstract-Background-47D.jpg&quot;);">
```

Case 3 :
**Please Try this first,**

Your theme have Visual Composer,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zvLtpksu1o

[image: **output after Case 2**]

Comment: I want to set the background image on a single page. Not background color.

Comment: same logic place there

Comment: I can see how you have added inline-css here `<div class="template-page col-sm-12 tpl-no" style="
    background-image: url(&quot;http://imagecolony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Abstract-Background-47D.jpg&quot;);">`

Comment: But I dont know where to find that HTML to add the CSS. It is not in the register.php file.

Comment: register is your page inside wordpress admin  area,right?

Comment: can you place register.php here?